# Print list item with in a list in python

Tags: python, printing, concatenation

if i have a list example

```
x = [1,2,3,["a","b","c"]]
```

How can I print from stack list within the list

Comment: What is the expected output? is it:
1
2
3
a
b
c
?

Comment: Let say i want to print 'c'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only print the elements within the nested list you can do:

```
x = [1,2,3,["a","b","c"]]
for elem in x:
    if isinstance(elem, list):
        print(*elem)
```

**Edit**
If you have a desired element from within the nested list:

```
desired_elem = "c"
for elem in x:
    if isinstance(elem, list):
        print(elem[elem.index(desired_elem)])
```

And of course that you can just reach that element using indexing.

```
print(x[2][1])
```

Comment: It is printing the list which is great. But what if I want to print only 'b' from that stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can access individual elements of a list by using [i] if the element received is also a list you can just access again:

```
x = [1,2,3,["a","b","c"]]
print(x[3][2])
```

outputs c